# Expose Python API to Kubernetes minikube deployment

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, nginx, minikube

I want to expose an API written in Python to a Minikube cluster. I have the following directory structure

```
- Dockerfile
- src
   - pyproject.toml
   - src
       - api.py
- nginx-chart
   - templates
       - deployment.yaml
       - service.yaml
   - chart.yaml
   - values.yaml
```

In api.py I have

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/root")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

def start():
    """Launched with `poetry run start` at root level"""
    uvicorn.run("src.api:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, reload=True)
```

In pyproject.toml I have

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "api"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "The API"
readme = "README.md"
authors = ["me"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
fastapi = "^0.95.0"
kubernetes = "^26.1.0"
uvicorn = "^0.21.1"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
black = "^23.3.0"
pytest = "^7.3.0"
isort = "^5.12.0"
flake8 = "^6.0.0"
mypy = "^1.2.0"
lxml = "^4.9.2"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = "src.api:start"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

In my Dockerfile I have

```
FROM python:3.9 as base

COPY src src

WORKDIR /src
RUN dir -s
RUN pip install poetry && poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["poetry", "run", "start"]
```

Deployment.yaml is

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
              protocol: TCP
```

service.yaml is

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - protocol: {{ .Values.service.protocol | default "TCP" }}
      port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
```

values.yaml

```yaml
replicaCount: 2

image:
  repository: <my docker>/<my_image>
  tag: "v0.0.2"
  pullPolicy: Always

service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 80
  targetPort: 8080
```

chart.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: nginx-chart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

I first run `minikube start` to start minikube. I then deploy with `helm upgrade --install service /nginx-chart` from the root of the directory.

The docker image builds (and is tagged with `v0.0.2`), and the helm command succeeds, however, I cannot find my api endpoint in the resulting deployment. Once deployed I run `kubectl proxy --port=8080` and then open the endpoint in my browser to obtain

```
{
  "paths": [
    "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apps",
    "/apis/apps/v1",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/autoscaling",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v1",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v2",
    "/apis/batch",
    "/apis/batch/v1",
    "/apis/certificates.k8s.io",
    "/apis/certificates.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/coordination.k8s.io",
    "/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/discovery.k8s.io",
    "/apis/discovery.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/events.k8s.io",
    "/apis/events.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io",
    "/apis/flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta2",
    "/apis/flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta3",
    "/apis/networking.k8s.io",
    "/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/node.k8s.io",
    "/apis/node.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/policy",
    "/apis/policy/v1",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/scheduling.k8s.io",
    "/apis/scheduling.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/autoregister-completion",
    "/healthz/etcd",
    "/healthz/log",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/aggregator-reload-proxy-client-cert",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-openapiv3-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/bootstrap-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-consumer",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-producer",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-filter",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-cluster-authentication-info-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-admission-initializer",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-identity-lease-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-identity-lease-garbage-collector",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-legacy-token-tracking-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/storage-object-count-tracker-hook",
    "/livez",
    "/livez/autoregister-completion",
    "/livez/etcd",
    "/livez/log",
    "/livez/ping",
    "/livez/poststarthook/aggregator-reload-proxy-client-cert",
    "/livez/poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/apiservice-openapiv3-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/bootstrap-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced",
    "/livez/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/livez/poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration",
    "/livez/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-consumer",
    "/livez/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-producer",
    "/livez/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-filter",
    "/livez/poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles",
    "/livez/poststarthook/scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-cluster-authentication-info-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-admission-initializer",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-identity-lease-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-identity-lease-garbage-collector",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-legacy-token-tracking-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/storage-object-count-tracker-hook",
    "/logs",
    "/metrics",
    "/openapi/v2",
    "/openapi/v3",
    "/openapi/v3/",
    "/openid/v1/jwks",
    "/readyz",
    "/readyz/autoregister-completion",
    "/readyz/etcd",
    "/readyz/etcd-readiness",
    "/readyz/informer-sync",
    "/readyz/log",
    "/readyz/ping",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/aggregator-reload-proxy-client-cert",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/apiservice-openapiv3-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/bootstrap-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-consumer",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-producer",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-filter",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-cluster-authentication-info-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-admission-initializer",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-identity-lease-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-identity-lease-garbage-collector",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-legacy-token-tracking-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/storage-object-count-tracker-hook",
    "/readyz/shutdown",
    "/version"
  ]
}
```

One of my pods has the following logs

```
Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/cakes']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [12]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

Where is my python api located?

## Edit

I added the following file `nginx-chart/templates/ingress.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-ingress
  annotations:
    app: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .Release.Name }}-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

with the following update to values.

```yaml
ingress:
  host: hello-world.info
```

Comment: @HarshManvar Thanks for your answer, I added an ingress file (shown in update) and followed the guide, but I still can't access the API in the browser.

Comment: what error are you seeing in browser ? did you updated the IP in etc/host ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are **misunderstanding** the `kubectl proxy --port=8080` that command is for accessing the **API's** of **Kubernetes**.

So you can manage the Deployment and service and other such stuff with that command.

You are running your own **Deployment** and applying it with the **Helm**, if POD and service are applied successfully.

You can check the status with

```
kubectl get pods & kubectl get svc
```

**Nginx** chart you are using is your point of contact to your API that will be managing the traffic for you.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:  
  name: example-ingress    
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1 
spec:   
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

You might have to create the **ingress**. Ingress is an object managed by the **Ingress** **controller** which is **nginx** in your case.

Your flow of traffic will be something like this

```
API request(browser) > Ingress (Rule) > Ingress controller (Rule/path match check) > service > Deployment > POD > Container
```

Check this official doc from **Kuberentes** using the **minikube** and **ingress** : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

With **minikube** you can enable the **nginx** **ingress** **controller** without installing the chart so you can follow the wiki will get a clear idea.